# Opening links with keystroke in iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm2

I love the incremental search and tab-expand to select feature in iTerm2. Is there any way to configure it to support *magically-open-selected-link* with a keystroke? Just like cmd-clicking a url?

Comment: Not quite understand the question. If you want to quick open a url, cmd+clicking will do the trick. If you don't want to use the keyboard, "right button" => "open selection as url" can open the url.

Comment: I want to quick open an url without using the mouse. I want a key combo equivalent for cmd + click

Comment: It seems iterm2 can not add a key-mapping to support such behavior, maybe you can work around though your editor(emacs/vim etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTerm2 supports "Open selection as url" when right click, but doesn't support to create shortcut for that.
**I hack [some code](https://github.com/sel-fish/iTerm2/wiki/How-to-create-shortcut-for-'open-selection-as-url') to support it, maybe it can help you somehow.**